# I get an error ddms Can't bind to local 8602 for debugger - no debugging for Android

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I am just starting develop a simple hello world application and I got this error and I cannot debug any application on AVD nor any device.
I am using Eclipse Juno and Windows 8.

```
[2012-11-11 10:57:37 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8610 for debugger
[2012-11-11 10:57:37 - ddmlib] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:575)
at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:348)
at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:421)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:837)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:805)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMonitor.java:765)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:652)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:44)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$3.run(DeviceMonitor.java:580)

[2012-11-11 10:58:41 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8602 for debugger
[2012-11-11 10:58:41 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8610 for debugger
[2012-11-11 10:58:41 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8602 for debugger
```

I checked many available solutions including:
disabling windows firewall / antivirus

adding a line "     127.0.0.1       localhost" into host file

checking if there was not another eclipse instance running in background (I have only one instance running)

restarting adb

recreating avd

restarting eclipse and my computer also didn't help

changing in Window -> Preferences -> Android -> DDMS "base local debugger port" and checking "use ADBHOST" with "127.0.0.1" also didn't help me.

checking with netstat -a that the ports are not in use

Please, maybe somebody can solve the madness so that the debugger will connect.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem since installing Windows 8.

Installing JRE 6 did solve the issue however it did work once without the need to to this..

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html#jre-6u34-oth-JPR

Answer (score 2):

OK I spent some hours to figure it out:
It turned out that the cause was Java 7. I uninstalled Java 7 and installed Java 6 and debugging works now!

Comment: Omar do you have the same problem?

Comment: it was, but it is solved but i don't remember which step solve it because i do multi step then check it to find it solved.